# df.to_csv(fileName, sep='|', header=True, index=False) produces column misalignment due to commas in column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, delimiter

I'm reading data from a SQL Server table into a dataframe using:

```
df = pd.read_sql(querystring, conn)
```

and then writing the dataframe to a CSV file using:

```
df.to_csv(fileName, sep='|', header=True, index=False)
```

One of the columns in the table is a comments field that may contain commas.  This is causing the CSV file that gets created has misaligned columns.

I was expecting the `sep='|'` parameter to `df.to_csv` to only separate columns, not replace commas within the columns.  How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Are you're sure it's a problem with the python part, and not your csv viewer (excel?). Can you post a line from the generated csv?

Comment: What do commas have to do with column alignment if your separator is `|`? Setting `sep` does _not_ replace commas in values.

Comment: skip comment column, import remaining columns and then add at the end to get complete list of columns in your dataframe.

Comment: @Joost I'm sure.  I'm opening the file in a text editor and all of the columns in the comment column have been replaced with | characters.

Comment: @LevLevitsky That's IS what is happening, however.  If I look at the column value in SQL Sever it looks like: 

Anogenital, Localized, Yellow

And my CSV file contains Anogenital| Localized| Yellow.

Comment: Does the pandas dataframe show commas in the comment column when you're printing it?

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Try to isolate the problem in the SQL part or the `to_csv` part.